# Could not find org.apache.jmeter:bom:5.4.1

Tags: gradle, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jmeter-plugins

I have a Jenkinsfile pipeline and in one of its stages I run some jmeter tests and generate the respective report.
This is my stage

```
  stage('Run Non-Functional tests - Windows'){
            when { expression { env.OS == 'BAT' }}
            steps {                
                dir('') {
                    bat 'gradlew.bat jmReport'
                }
            }
        }
```

and this is my build gradle

```
import de.qualersoft.jmeter.gradleplugin.task.*

dependencies {
  jmeterPlugin("kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.10") 
} 

plugins {
    id "de.qualersoft.jmeter" version "2.1.0"
}

tasks.register('jmRun',JMeterRunTask) {
    jmxFile.set("TestPlan.jmx")
}

tasks.register("jmReport",JMeterReportTask) {
    jmxFile.set("TestPlan.jmx")
    dependsOn("jmRun")
    deleteResults=true
}
```

When I try to run my pipeline it fails with the following error

```
Execution failed for task ':jmRun'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':jmeterPlugin'.
   > Could not find org.apache.jmeter:bom:5.4.1.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find org.apache.jmeter:bom:5.4.1.
     Required by:
         project : > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_core:5.4.1
         project : > org.apache.jmeter:ApacheJMeter_core:5.4.1 > org.apache.jmeter:jorphan:5.4.1
```

Why does this happen? Is it some kind of bug with JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JMeter Bug 64465](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64465) which contains the workaround.

Or just consider switching to [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

As said earlier, the main reason is that many jmeter-libraries/plugins depends on 'org.apache.jmeter:bom:', which unfortunately isn't available in any maven-repository. As a workaround, use the below code in your dependencies section:

```
jmeterPlugin("kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-tst:2.5") {
  jmeter.tool.applyBomWorkaround(this)
}
```